Can't we have a spring boot admin of version 3.0.x(Java 17) and client spring boot version of 2.7.13(java 1.8)?
I have my client application of version 2.7.13 which runs on java 1.8. And I have a spring boot admin which is of version 3.0.x and runs on java 17(since spring boot 3.0.x needs java 17). Can I pair this combination for monitoring the client on admin server?
When I tried this the application is not registering to admin
